# Multi-line output from laptop to several speakers

Tags: speakers, multichannel, laptop

I'd like to play many (currently up to eight, but possibly more in the future) distinct lines of audio from my laptop, and play each line from a separate speaker.

The audio source is a Java program I've written. I can produce a single stream of multi-channel audio (one channel per speaker), or produce several streams of single-channel audio (one channel per line), whichever works better.

My laptop is a Macbook with USB-C ports (and a few others, but hopefully USB-C is sufficient).

I obviously don't have eight USB-C ports on my laptop, so I'm guessing some kind of intermediate hardware will be necessary to allow my laptop to connect to my speakers.

What kind of equipment do I need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty simple. You need an audio interface that has eight separate channels of output. Make sure it is not a 2 or 4 channel interface with multiple outputs for the same 2 or 4 channels (headphone outputs in addition to the monitor/line outputs), but actually 8 separate channels.

This is only if all eight channels of your audio are different. If they are all the same, you can use a signal multiplier.